# Typescript find the the variable with the largest value

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScripts/JavaScript,

How do I find the variable that contains the largest int value?

```
var id = 0; var ii = 1; var is = 2; var ic = 4;
```

Or how do I find the field that contains the largest int value?

```
{id : 0, ii : 1, is : 2, ic : 4}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.max` will tell you the largest value of its arguments: `Math.max(id, ii, is, ic)`. From there you can use the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj= {id : 0, ii : 1, is : 2, ic : 4};
var max= Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var max_key=undefined;

for(var key in obj){
  if(obj[key] > max)
  {
      max_key = key;
      max = obj[key];
  }
}

document.write("The key with the maximum value is: "+max_key+" whose value is: "+max);
```

Create object, set var `max` value and var `max_key` value. Then using for loop visit each key in object and check is there any value of key is greater than `max`.